# Convergence of complex power series $z^{n!}$ at boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm revising for an exam at the moment and I'm struggling with part of a question.

I'm asked to find the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }z^{n!}$ and then find where it converges on the boundary.

By the ratio test I have R=1. Clearly for z=1 and z=-1 the series diverges but for the complex values I can't determine the behaviour at all, could somebody give me a hint? I've tried writing z in polar form but I can't seem to get anywhere with that either.

Comment: If the summand doesn't go to zero, can the sum converge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, by the ratio test the radius of convergence as a power series about $0$ is indeed $R=1$, so the series must converge in $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1 \}$. Lets see what happens if $z \in \partial D=\{ z: |z|=1\}$. Consider the set 
$$
E=\{ e^{2\pi i \cdot r} : r \in \mathbb{Q} \} \subset \partial D 
$$
For every $z \in E$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{2\pi i \cdot  r n!} .
$$
But clearly for each $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ there exist $N=N(r)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $r n! \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $n\geq N$, and thus $e^{2\pi i \cdot r n!}=e^0=1$ for all $n\geq N$. Then if $z \in E$, 
$$ 
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^N z^{n!} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty 1
$$
thus the series diverges for all $z \in E$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $E= \{ e^{2\pi i \cdot r} : r \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ is dense in $\partial D= \{ e^{2\pi i \cdot t} : t \in \mathbb{R} \}$, which gives that the series diverges for all $z \in \overline{E}=\partial D$. Then the series only converges in $D$ since the points on $\partial D$ are all singularities.

Comment: The last step uses uniform convergence, right?

Comment: @nayrb I do not see the use of uniform convergence on the proof. Precisely which step are you thinking it must be used? How and why ?

Comment: Divergence at all points does not follow from the fact that it diverges for all roots of unity. There are power series converging on almost every point in the boundary but diverging on a dense set, see for instance https://mathoverflow.net/a/182467/23106 for an example.

Comment: It diverges since the general term does not go to zero when $n$ goes to infinity.